# Check if item is in ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django

Consider this model:

```
class pm_thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

What would be the best way to check that a user is in the ManyToManyField? Example:

```
thread = get_object_or_404(pm_thread, pk=thread_id)
if not thread.participants.contains(request.user):
    return HttpResponse("403 FORBIDDEN",status=403)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator:

```
if not request.user in thread.participants.all():
    ...
```

Comment: Error: `argument of type 'ManyRelatedManager' is not iterable`

Comment: Updated the answer with that change :)

Comment: I would expect that thread.participants contains the primary keys of the users. So would it be possible to find the result without making a call to the database (with .call() in your example)

Answer (score 10):

Other answers call `.all()`, which does a query to retrieve all objects in the relationship (all participants), and then uses Python code to check if the user is included.

A better approach would be to query whether the user is included in the relationship directly, using a filtered query.

```py
if not thread.participants.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    return HttpResponse("403 FORBIDDEN",status=403)
```

Note that `thread.paricipants` is a Django QuerySet in and of itself.

Answer (score 5):

Since I can't comment under @Harmish, I'll have to point that under the PEP8 standard, membership should be `x not in` and not `not x in`

Therefore, your code would look like:

```
if request.user not in thread.participants.all():
    ...
```

Source: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations